# How can I run node.js Express in production mode via sudo?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, development-environment, express, production-environment

I'm using the npm package [express](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#configuration) version 2.5.2 with node version .0.6.5. I appear to be running bash version 4.1.5 on Debian 4.4.5.

I'm trying to run my server in production mode but it still runs in development mode.

I run these commands in my bash shell:

```
$ export NODE_ENV=production
$ echo $NODE_ENV
production
$ sudo echo $NODE_ENV
production
$ sudo node bootstrap.js
```

I have this code inside bootstrap.js:

```
var bootstrap_app = module.exports = express.createServer();
//...
console.log(bootstrap_app.settings.env);
```

and here's what I see printed to standard out:

```
development
```

Is this a problem with my usage, or my system?

**EDIT:**
Thanks to ThiefMaster for his properly identifying that this issue stems from my running node as root. ThiefMaster suggested using iptables to forward from port 80 to an unprivileged port, but my system gives me an error. Moving this discussion to superuser.com or serverfault.com (link to follow)

Comment: Most environment variables are unset when using sudo for security reasons. So you cannot pass that environment variable to node without modifying your sudoers file to allow that variable to passt through. However, you shouldn't run node as root anyway. If you just need it for port 80, run node on an unprivileged port and setup an iptables forward to map port 80 to that port.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

I ran one of my non-port-80 apps and it correctly identified the environment as production!
You should post this as an answer - I'll accept it.

Thanks again!

Comment: I just attempted installing and using iptables (iptables -t -nat L) and got the error "iptables v1.4.8: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded."
Debian 4.4 is a rather old version, right? /proc/version says "Linux version 3.1.9-vs2.3.2.5"

Comment: I did. Somebody thought it should be converted to a comment. And you can only setup the iptables forwarding as root. Posted the answer again.

Comment: Btw, `sudo echo $NODE_ENV` works because the variable is substituted so what sudo sees is `echo "production"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most environment variables are unset when using sudo for security reasons. So you cannot pass that environment variable to node without modifying your sudoers file to allow that variable to passt through.

However, you shouldn't run node as root anyway. So here's a good workaround:
If you just need it for port 80, run node on an unprivileged port and setup an iptables forward to map port 80 to that port:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -d 1.2.3.4/32 -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 2.3.4.5:1234
```

Replace 1.2.3.4 with your public IP, 2.3.4.5 with the IP node runs on (could be the public one or 127.0.0.1) and 1234 with the port node runs on.

---

With a sufficiently recent kernel that has capability support you could also grant the `node` executable the `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` privilege using the following command as root:

```
setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /usr/bin/node
```

Note that this will allow any user on your system to open privileged ports using node!

Comment: I tried the first solution, using iptables, and I'm still having trouble running it - even using my sudoer privileges. I've posted the whole of the error message as an edit to my question (to make use of the formatting it allows)

Comment: It would probably be better to ask about that on http://superuser.com or http://serverfault.com.

Comment: Why not use `authbind`?

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo NODE_ENV=production /usr/local/bin/node  /usr/local/apps/test/app.js
```